# CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '...' when migrating using Flask-Migrate

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I started using Flask-Migrate today and installed it on a test project.
However i am getting following error:

> alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by
>   'e39d16e62810'

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. run "python create_db.py"
2. run "flask db init"
3. add column "name" to Entry-model
4. run "flask db migrate"

**EDIT:**
After removing `migrations` directory and repeating the process i am getting the same error after running "flask db migrate".
I also tried using a `manage.py` file with flask-script --> same issue

**Error:**

```
(venv_mentz) H:\Flask-API-Test>python manage.py db migrate
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 143, in _catch_revision_errors
    yield
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 206, in get_revisions
    return self.revision_map.get_revisions(id_)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 299, in get_revisions
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 304, in get_revisions
    for rev_id in resolved_id)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 304, in <genexpr>
    for rev_id in resolved_id)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 362, in _revision_for_ident
    resolved_id)
alembic.script.revision.ResolutionError: No such revision or branch 'e39d16e62810'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 417, in run
    result = self.handle(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 386, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\flask_script\commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 197, in migrate
    version_path=version_path, rev_id=rev_id)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 176, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 425, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 81, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 83, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations\env.py", line 87, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations\env.py", line 80, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 836, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 321, in run_migrations
    for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 156, in retrieve_migrations
    revision_context.run_autogenerate(rev, context)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 415, in run_autogenerate
    self._run_environment(rev, migration_context, True)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\autogenerate\api.py", line 425, in _run_environment
    if set(self.script_directory.get_revisions(rev)) != \
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 206, in get_revisions
    return self.revision_map.get_revisions(id_)
  File "c:\users\marschall\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 174, in _catch_revision_errors
    compat.raise_from_cause(util.CommandError(resolution))
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 194, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 143, in _catch_revision_errors
    yield
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 206, in get_revisions
    return self.revision_map.get_revisions(id_)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 299, in get_revisions
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 304, in get_revisions
    for rev_id in resolved_id)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 304, in <genexpr>
    for rev_id in resolved_id)
  File "H:\Flask-API-Test\venv_mentz\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\revision.py", line 362, in _revision_for_ident
    resolved_id)
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by 'e39d16e62810'
```

**My file structure looks like this:**

```
app
-- views
----- __init__.py
----- main.py
-- __init__.py
-- config.py
-- models.py
instance
-- __init__.py
-- config.py
create_db.py
dev.db
run.py
```

**My app factory:**

```
from flask import Flask
from instance.config import app_config
from flask_migrate import Migrate

def create_app(config_name):
    """ Creates a runnable app.
        This app will be using the config with name "config_name".
    """
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # Loading the the config from instance folder with name "config_name"
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    # Loading generic config from 'config.py'
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    # Registering this app at db
    from app.models import db
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    from app import models, views

    return app
```

**My run.py:**

```
""" This script runs a the app with the given configuration. """

from app import create_app

# Configuration used to run the app
config_name = 'dev'

# Creating the app by using the required configuration
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**And my create_db.py file to create the database using models.py:**

```
""" This script creates the database defined in app.models. """

from app import create_app

app = create_app('dev')
from app.models import db

# Telling SQLAlchemy what app should be used as the database model
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

**This is my models.py:**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Entries'
    layer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "ID: {}; text: {}".format(self.layer_id, self.text)
```

**EDIT: manage.py:**

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app import create_app
from app import models
from app.models import db

app = create_app('dev')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: can you check if you have a migration folder in your application directory?

Comment: There is/was no migration folder at the beginning. However it gets created when running "flask db init"

Comment: Delete the `migrations` directory and repeat the whole process again please. If you get the error, please add the command that gave you the error, along with the complete output to your question.

Comment: I already tried removing migrations directory but i didn´t solve the issue.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when I modified my models.py and tried migrating a second time. The issue is when you hit flask db init for the first time, it will create a table named alembic_version, you should drop that table from the database and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 63):

you delete the migration directory but the version has been saved in the database, so you have to delete the version info in the dabase,
run

`delete from alembic_version;`

in mysql shell.

As suggested  by @mirekphd,  If this is a developing environment or a single app for test, just delete it, Else BACKUP the data in the table.

Comment: This worked for me!. 
run 'DELETE FROM alembic_version' on the db terminal on your local or on the server.
Thanks.

Comment: Make a copy of that existing `alembic_version`, because that will most certainly break the other app that expects your db to have that "wrong" version you are deleting.

Comment: REFER @Saji ANSWER, it'll help you solve the issue without destroying the database.

Comment: droping the table also works.

Comment: I had this issue, and this answer made me realise that i had to delte a previous migration because i was sharing the same database for another project, and there was c conflict there.

Answer (score 15):

I tried this on flask and it worked:

```
python app.py db revision --rev-id e39d16e62810  
python app.py db migrate  
python app.py db upgrade
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case I have accidentally deleted the most recent migration file but the alembic version (alembic_version) table refers to the deleted version.

So instead of droping the entire database, you can change the version_num field in the alembic_version table.

Following steps worked for me:

> - Find the head using  `db history`
> - Update the version_num field to the head version.
> - run migrate using `db migrate`
> - upgrade the database `db upgrade`

Comment: This is the correct answer and steps to follow if you don't want to dump the entire db

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this solution. My challenge is a bit different. I have a web app running very well locally on localhost. The issue comes when it is deployed to Heroku. Every attempt to run `heroku run flask db upgrade` returns `ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by 'b824fd5038af'`. This is after deleting the migrations and `app.db` files and running migrations all over again. So, even when I run `heroku run flask db history`, I can see that the version 'b824fd5038af'` doesn't exists. Any further attempts is halted by this issue

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be placed FIRST - 
I did a mistake and didn't scroll down to this answer so found this out myself, 
could have saved me half an hour!

Comment: This is just the right thing to do!

Comment: Hi Gitau, Check this solution out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69152121/644384.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have accidentally deleted the most recent migration file but the alembic version (alembic_version) table refers to the deleted version.

I tried the following:

```
flask db revision --rev-id [revision-id]
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time this happens, if you are at the development stage where you don't have much data to loose, you can drop the database and create a fresh one, alternatively, you can delete the migrations and begin the whole cycle again, for sqlite, it is all about deleting the sqlite file in your application, and beginning this cycle again. I hope to find the best solution to this verry soon.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the history entry from the database will solve the issue.

**Error**: alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by 'e39d16e62810'

```
select * from alembic_version where version_num='e39d16e62810'
```

Option 1: Update the record with your latest revision id

```
update alembic_version set version_num='<your_version_num>' where version_num='e39d16e62810'
```

Option 2: Delete this record:

```
delete from alembic_version where version_num='e39d16e62810'
```

Comment: deleting the version is only ok if you want to start from the very beginning.
you should add that in the description! 
the exception can raise if you have an inconsistent state / corrupt state and in that case, you should use history, migrate and upgrade to fix that

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that another flask app was already connected to the same database, so I just created a new database, and changed:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/newDataBaseName'
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case reason for the error was the relative path to sqlite db.

Fixed it by specifying the absolute path

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"sqlite:///{os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir, 'db.sqlite')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another cause of problems - making two flask projects in the same virtual environment.

I tried to make fake twin project for performance testing.

- copied crucial parts of the original project
- created new database
- made changes in configuration file to point to new database
- `flask db init`,
- `flask db migrate`
- got this error at first migration.

Then I did only one thing - created new python environment for this twin project - and error disappeared.

PS. Maybe it is possible to create two flask projects in the same environment, but I was not able to find solution.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, since I was in the initial phase, I had the luxury of deleting the database file directly i.e. in my project folder there was a .sqlite file, so I deleted it by right-clicking it.
But please keep in mind that I was in the initial phase, so I won't suggest this if you are
not in the starting phase.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error message but in my case it's because I used wrong database name in the connection string. Check your connection string

Error Message:

> ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by 'a80ab7ca5e1a'

Reason:
My connection string was:

> mysql+pymysql://kaunda:kaunda@localhost:3306/smis

Instead of

> mysql+pymysql://kaunda:kaunda@localhost:3306/WorkFolder

The revision identified by "a80ab7ca5e1a" belongs to the database "smis" not "WorkFolder"

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you `set FLASK_APP=app.py` on windows or `export FLASK_APP=app.py` on MAC before running `flask db init`, then `flask db migrate -m "message"` and `flask db upgrade`. You can check this link for more info https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Migrate/

Comment: This is good advice in general,  but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, I did it and it worked. I deleted the migration folder and all the __pycache folders and then set FLASK_APP=app.py and finally ran the flask db commands. Voila!