# Unable to find source of: ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by '..'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-migrate

I am trying to run migrations from command line and keep getting error:
`ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by 'faf3ebfbe667'`

As suggested in other posts I deleted my sqlite db and migration folder (several times). I recreated virtual environment as well. I checked all files in my project folder for a reference to the revision and I cant find anything there. The error persists.
I tried to drop alembic_version in db but such table does not exists.

I try to run migrations from comand line as below:

```
set FLASK_APP=my_app/__init__.py
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Comment: What is the value of your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` configuration variable?

Comment: It is: 'sqlite:///site.db'

Comment: In `alembic/versions`:  (1) delete all files in the __pycache__ folder (2) grep  for "faf3ebfbe667":  if it appears in a file  you will need to correct any references, or remove the file if it isn't part of your alembic history.  Best t otake a backup of `alembic/versions` before doing this. (Or you could update the question with your findings).

Answer (score 13):

It's my late answer, but I hope it will be helpful for you.

You can use this way to resolve the issue.

```
$ flask db revision --rev-id faf3ebfbe667
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db upgrade
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Go to your database and delete the below table:
`alembic_versions`

Answer (score 4):

Delete in your database the table

> alembic_version

and create it again using

```
$ python run.py db stamp heads
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the folder versions inside migrations (Ex: migrations)

1. If you do not see the folder versions or  there is not a revision inside the folder versions type the following command to create a revision

   - flask db revision
2. If there is already a revision inside the folder
   open it and replace the revision id by 'faf3ebfbe667' as follows

   - `revision = "faf3ebfbe667"`
3. type again the command `flask db migrate`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned above that your database URL is `sqlite:///site.db`. This is a relative path, the file `site.db` will be created in the current directory, whatever that might be.

Since you said there is an apparent reference to an inexistent database revision, my guess is that you have more than one database file, and the one you deleted is not the one that is being picked up from the current directory of your running application.

I suggest you switch to a absolute path URL to avoid problems. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but even if it isn't you should use an absolute path. See example below:

```py
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'site.db')
```

This will make the absolute location of the database file the same location as the script in which this code is included.

Answer (score 0):

My case was **docker**, **python 3.8**, and **ubuntu 20.04 lts**. The error message was:

> ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by '3d42f5f6cf4b'

Since I did not have such a version file in migration/versions, so I just destroyed all containers and images and run `sudo docker-compose build` again, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I did the following to resolve the error:

1. Went to `migrations/versions` and located the most recently created migration file.
2. Grabbed that migration's revision identifier (should be under the imports, under a comment that reads `# revision identifiers, used by Alembic`).
3. In the `alembic_version` table, I updated the `version_num` column with the revision identifier from step two.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the **_***pycache****_* , **migrations** folders and the database. Then make sure you `set FLASK_APP=app.py` on windows or `export FLASK_APP=app.py` on MAC before running `flask db init`, then `flask db migrate -m "message"` and `flask db upgrade`. You can check this link for more info https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Migrate/